# Using Slashbox/Diagbox in Pgfplotstable

Tags: tables, pgfplots, pgfplotstable, csv, diagbox

I have a csv file in this form

```
,0.01,0.1,1.0,10.0,100.0
0,0.3837,0.8259,0.9386,0.9386,0.9386
1,0.3837,0.9464,0.9386,0.9386,0.9386
2,0.3976,0.95,0.9386,0.9386,0.9386
3,0.8259,0.9386,0.9386,0.9386,0.9386
4,0.9464,0.9386,0.9386,0.9386,0.9386
```

I have successfully inserting this as table in my latex file using Pgfplotstable package. This is the screenshot:

[image]

My problem is I want to make top leftmost cell which is currently empty as a diagonal cell with two element A and B. A refers to leftmost row and B refers to top column. I know that I have to use slashbox or diagbox to do this, but I don't know how to use it inside pgfplotstable. This is the working example of  the table.

```
\documentclass[a4,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}


    \begin{table}[h!]
        \caption{Example Table}
        \label{tab:polytune}
        \begin{center}
            \pgfplotstabletypeset[
            col sep=comma,
            header = has colnames,
            string type,
            display columns/0/.style={column name = ,column type={|l|},
                postproc cell content/.code={% <--- style row 2 (=index 1) of column "2"
                    \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=0 
                    \pgfkeysalso{@cell content=0.01}% <---make it red
                    \fi
                    \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=1 
                    \pgfkeysalso{@cell content=0.1}% <---make it red
                    \fi
                    \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=2 
                    \pgfkeysalso{@cell content=1}% <---make it red
                    \fi
                    \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=3 
                    \pgfkeysalso{@cell content=10}% <---make it red
                    \fi
                    \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=4 
                    \pgfkeysalso{@cell content=100}% <---make it red
                    \fi
                },
            },
            display columns/1/.style={column type={l|}},
            display columns/2/.style={column type={l|}},
            display columns/3/.style={column type={l|}},
            display columns/4/.style={column type={l|}},
            display columns/5/.style={column type={l|}},
            every head row/.style={before row=\hline,after row=\hline},
            every nth row={1}{before row=\hline},
            every last row/.style={after row=\hline},
            ]{
        ,0.01,0.1,1.0,10.0,100.0
        0,0.3837,0.8259,0.9386,0.9386,0.9386
        1,0.3837,0.9464,0.9386,0.9386,0.9386
        2,0.3976,0.95,0.9386,0.9386,0.9386
        3,0.8259,0.9386,0.9386,0.9386,0.9386
        4,0.9464,0.9386,0.9386,0.9386,0.9386    
        }
        \end{center}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. I just added it to the `before row` key.

```
\documentclass[a4,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}


    \begin{table}[h!]
        \caption{Example Table}
        \label{tab:polytune}
        \begin{center}
            \pgfplotstabletypeset[
            col sep=comma,
            header = has colnames,
            string type,
            display columns/0/.style={column name = ,column type={|l|},
                postproc cell content/.code={% <--- style row 2 (=index 1) of column "2"
                    \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=0 
                    \pgfkeysalso{@cell content=0.01}% <---make it red
                    \fi
                    \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=1 
                    \pgfkeysalso{@cell content=0.1}% <---make it red
                    \fi
                    \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=2 
                    \pgfkeysalso{@cell content=1}% <---make it red
                    \fi
                    \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=3 
                    \pgfkeysalso{@cell content=10}% <---make it red
                    \fi
                    \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=4 
                    \pgfkeysalso{@cell content=100}% <---make it red
                    \fi
                },
            },
            display columns/1/.style={column type={l|}},
            display columns/2/.style={column type={l|}},
            display columns/3/.style={column type={l|}},
            display columns/4/.style={column type={l|}},
            display columns/5/.style={column type={l|}},
            every head row/.style={before row={\hline\diagbox[innerwidth = 2.5em,
            height = 3ex]{}{}},after row=\hline},
            every nth row={1}{before row=\hline},
            every last row/.style={after row=\hline},
            ]{
        ,0.01,0.1,1.0,10.0,100.0
        0,0.3837,0.8259,0.9386,0.9386,0.9386
        1,0.3837,0.9464,0.9386,0.9386,0.9386
        2,0.3976,0.95,0.9386,0.9386,0.9386
        3,0.8259,0.9386,0.9386,0.9386,0.9386
        4,0.9464,0.9386,0.9386,0.9386,0.9386    
        }
        \end{center}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]